# Transforming between matrices of SO($3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, mathematical-physics

The $SO(3)$ $3\times 3$ matrices are well known in physics:

$J_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{0&1&0\\1&0&1\\ 0&1&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ J_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{0&-i&0\\i&0&-i\\ 0&i&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ J_3=\left(\matrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1}\right)$

However, we can also build another group of 3x3 matrices that still satisfy the same Lie algebra $so(3)$:

$K_1=\left(\matrix{0&0&0\\0&0&-i\\ 0&i&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ K_2=\left(\matrix{0&0&i\\0&0&0\\ -i&0&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ K_3=\left(\matrix{0&-i&0\\i&0&0\\ 0&0&0}\right)$

Which I found in the 5th page of this document https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS3120/v12/grpt3120E.pdf.

Since the representation of $so(3)$ is unique these matrices should be related to one another, particularly by a transformation of the form:

$K_i=SJ_iS^{-1}$

Where $S$ is a $3\times 3$ unitary matrix. While I know how to convert one couple of matrices from one to another (for example, an $S_1$ that converts only $K_1\rightarrow J_1$), I've never seen how to convert from one group of matrices to another. I've looked everywhere and tried different combinations, but I can't seem to find a single matrix $M$ that transforms all the $K_i$ to $J_i$.

I just found in an article that the matrix $S$ should have the following form,
$$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{-1&0&1\\ -i&0&-i\\ 0&\sqrt{2}&0} \right).$$

However, I'm still trying to see where it came from. Could you give me any guidance, or if there's a general procedure?

Edit: I found out that this process is changing a basis of orthonormal matrices from one basis to another. I still haven't found any explicit procedure, though.

Comment: I've marked this one as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375563/66086).

The idea is to transform the 3d vectors these sets of matrices act on.

Consider the eigenvectors of $K_3$, the transposes of $(-1,-i,0)/\sqrt{2}$ for eigenvalue 1; of $(0,0,1)$ for null eigenvalue; and of $(1,-i,0)/\sqrt{2}$ for eigenvalue -1. Utilize them as column vectors of your matrix *S*.

What basis change converts them to the evident eigenvectors of $J_3$, the defining structure of the [spherical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis)? *S* is then the diagonalizing transformation for it, namely $S^{-1} K_3 S\equiv J_3$.

Having found this basis change, how does it transform all 3 matrices from the Cartesian to the spherical basis? You are done. That is, the other two generators come in for the ride: The $J_2, J_3$ were *found* this way. They are not arbitrary matrices: they are *defined* as similarity transforms of the *K*s preserving the Lie algebra.

- The point is all 3 generators, in any basis, *have to obey the same Lie algebra*, so they *must* transform under the very same similarity transformation to preserve this algebra.