# Finding matrix transformation between two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Sorry if this is a naive question, but I've been stuck for 2 weeks on this particular problem and I didn't find anything useful in linear algebra books.

I'm looking to find how to construct a matrix that transforms a basis composed of $3\times 3$ matrices $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ to another basis composed of other $3\times 3$ matrices $(B_1,B_2,B_3)$.

I know we can transform one matrix to another with a similarity transformation:

$A=P^{-1}BP$

Where the rows of $P$ come from the eigenvectors of the matrix $B$. However, this is the first time I need to find a matrix that converts all three matrices $A_i$ to $B_i$, so I don't know to build this matrix.

As an example, I found in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Lie_algebra that they can convert from the Cartesian to the spherical representation of SO(3) matrices using a similarity transformation matrix $U$, namely $UJ_aU^\dagger =K_a$.

They go from this (spherical) basis,
$$J_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{0&1&0\\1&0&1\\ 0&1&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ J_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{0&-i&0\\i&0&-i\\ 0&i&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ J_3=\left(\matrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1}\right),$$
to this (Cartesian) basis,
$$K_1=\left(\matrix{0&0&0\\0&0&-i\\ 0&i&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ K_2=\left(\matrix{0&0&i\\0&0&0\\ -i&0&0}\right) \ \ ; \ \ K_3=\left(\matrix{0&-i&0\\i&0&0\\ 0&0&0}\right),$$
through the following unitary matrix,
$$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\matrix{-1&0&1\\-i&0&-i\\ 0&\sqrt{2}&0}\right).$$

But I've no idea how they built up this transformation matrix.

Comment: You look for bases of *which space*?

Comment: The vectors that you’re working with happen to be matrices. In order to find a change-of-basis _matrix_, you’ll have to “flatten” them via some isomorphism between $M_{3\times3}$ and $\mathbb R^9$.

Comment: In general, a similarity transformation can’t work. They preserve determinants, so what are you going to do if $\det A_i\ne\det B_i$ for your two bases?

Comment: Sorry, but you point me to an example of how to do such isomorphisms? I read it about in Wikipedia but I got confused with the notation, however I understand it's some kind of transformation to pass from one space to another. Indeed, for this case such transformation works because both couples have the same determinant, but in the general case there would be no way to apply a similarity tranaformation.

Comment: [M Rose](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_theory_of_angular_momentum.html?id=QApRAAAAMAAJ), p 105. It is straightforward, given the structure constants of the respective bases' Lie algebra.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375563/66086). The spherical basis is characterized by the eigenvectors of $J_3$, of course. Observe how these identify with the eigenvectors of $K_3$. Can you now reconstruct the basis change *U*?

Comment: [Answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2917099/362193). A common similarity transformation for all 3 matrices is required to preserve their Lie Algebra. *U* is the diagonalizing similarity transformation for $iK_3$. Diagonal $J_3$ is essentially the *definition* of the spherical basis!